# Would solving this equation prove square freeness of fermat numbers?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering if proving

$$p^2\cdot b-1=2^{2^n}$$

has no solutions in $\mathbb{N}$ for $p$ a prime, it would prove square freeness of fermat numbers?

Comment: thanks for editing :D didnt get the double exponent

Comment: Yes. Of course. Why do you ask?

Comment: i just wanted to know if i wasnt wrong ^^ thank you

Comment: and what would proving a^2*b^2-1=2^2^n has no solutions for a>1, say?

Comment: Same thing. Come on. It says there's no square dividing $2^{2^n}+1$; it says the Fermat number is squarefree.

Comment: But i proved that already.. and i think it was too easy to be the same thing xD